# Can I use FTP (IIS) behind a loadbalancer? (Azure LB)

Tags: azure, iis, ftp, load-balancing, azure-virtual-network

I have an Azure loadbalancer with load balancing rules for http, https and now ftp (port 21). I have IIS FTP installed on my VM's, and I can connect via Filezilla fine using the VM's IP directly, but using the loadbalancer IP the connecting ends up timing out even though it says the directly listing is successful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but using the loadbalancer IP the connecting ends up timing out even
>   though it says the directly listing is successful.

**We can use Azure Load Balancer for FTP**(IIS), but we have to **add data channel ports to load balancer rules**.
I had test in my lab, and it works for me, here is the load balancing rules settings:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it

Comment: ok, please let me know if you would like further assistance:)

Comment: I'm trying it with filezilla (server) now (iis wont work due to several reasons specific to my case). But I added the rules but it still doesnt work. Keep gettting: Response: 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
Response: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"

Comment: @user2713516 how many ports have you added? in my test open ports 10001-10005, so i add port 10001-10005.

Comment: I opened the same ones, I think filezilla has different ports? I configued 60000-60000 for the port range, so I added 60000. Another thing, If I use the load balancing rules, and I exclude traffic based on IP? Using the NSG of the VM I can select 'loadbalancer' but that means all traffic?

Comment: @user2713516 I mean what the port range are you opened? in my lab, my FTP open  data channel ports 10000-10005, please check your FTP's data channel ports.

Comment: I got it to work, my issue was I think that I had a 'range' of only 1 port for the data channel. I enlarged the range to 10 ports, added all 10 to the load balancer AND the NSG (and windows firewall) and it works now. thanks